# App Status Messages

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

**The Background**

I'm developing an app that has a Status Window; its purpose is to show various errors that might appear during the app's lifecycle:

[image: Status Window]

As you can see from my quick mockup, each error can be interacted with. For instance, touching an error related to settings might switch to the Settings UIViewController. Other errors might be "status-only" -- touching those might merely remove them from the Status Window.

**The Question**

Will you point me toward an appropriate method of storing these messages and their related actions? I'm swimming in the possibilities. I want these errors to be persistent, so something like Core Data seems to make sense (although, in my heart of hearts, Core Data seems really immense and perhaps unsuited for something this "simple").

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You could use the `NSUserDefaults` database?

Comment: @SantaClaus - I hadn't considered that; isn't `NSUserDefaults` intended for things like properties (and not error states, which might change frequently)? I don't actually know. :)

Comment: No, it is not ment for this, but it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data seems overkill for this. I think the suggestion with `NSUserDefaults` is a reasonable one.

You could construct an `NSArray` and store in it the error dictionaries with numbers and strings. Seems straight-forward enough.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Thanks for your thoughts - I know this is probably an easy question to experienced iOS devs, but I appreciate your thoughts.